# Python Turtle Drawing Assignment - Trouble with assigning variables

Tags: python, variables, turtle-graphics

I have an assignment due in a few hours and I'm stuck as to what to do. 
I am using python 3.

I keep trying to run the code, but I get errors. At this point I figured I'd ask for help.

Thank you in Advance!

Instructions: http://people.uncw.edu/cferner/Classes/csc231/Assignment1.html

```
 import turtle
 import random


class myRectangle:

def __var__(self):
    self.__x
    self.__y
    self.__width
    self.__height
    self.__color

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
    self.__x = x
    self.__y = y
    self.__width = width
    self.__height = height
    self.__color = color

def getX(self):
    return self.__x

def setX(self, x):
    self.__x = x

def getY(self):
    return self.__y

def setY(self, y):
    self.__y = y

def getWidth(self):
    return self.__width

def setWidth(self, width):
    self.__width = width

def getHeight(self):
    return self.__height

def setHeight(self, height):
    self.__height = height

def getColor(self):
    return self.__color

def setColor(self, color):
    self.__color = color

def draw(self, turtle):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(self.getX(), self.getY())
    turtle.heading(0)
    turtle.pencolor("blue")
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(self.__width())
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(self.__height())
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(self.__width())
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(self.__height())
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()


def main():

wn = turtle.TurtleScreen
mr = myRectangle
phil = turtle.Turtle()
macie = turtle.Turtle()
sashi = turtle.Turtle()
roxie = turtle.Turtle()
darla = turtle.Turtle()
sammy = turtle.Turtle()

phil.pencolor("blue")
phil.pensize(7)

listofcolors = ("blue", "red", "yellow", "orange", "pink", "green")
c = random.choice(listofcolors)

xy = random.randrange(-200, 201)
wh = random.randrange(1, 151)

for i in [phil, macie, sashi, roxie, darla, sammy]:
    mr.setColor(c)
    mr.setX(xy)
    mr.setY(xy)
    mr.setWidth(wh)
    mr.setHeight(wh)





main()
```

Errors:

```
     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 
    "/Users/Desktop/OneDrive - UNC-Wilmington/UNCW Files/Summer 
      2017/CSC 231/Assignment 1/turtleRectangle.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Desktop/OneDrive - UNC-Wilmington/UNCW Files/Summer 
   2017/CSC 231/Assignment 1/turtleRectangle.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
     File "/Users/Desktop/OneDrive - UNC-Wilmington/UNCW Files/Summer 
  2017/CSC 231/Assignment 1/turtleRectangle.py", line 92, in main
   mr.setColor()
   TypeError: setColor() missing 2 required positional arguments: 
  'self' and 'color'

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Download link for Python file](https://uncw4-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pjw5785_uncw_edu/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=070aedc7e9e02402faab2436d359025ef&authkey=AWhH1vXMjR0VaDYwefibLuQ)

Comment: Could you also post the errors

Comment: Cool looking at it right now

Comment: Appreciate it!!

Comment: the fact that the assignment asks that you name mangle to 'make the data private' is mind boggling

Comment: It's either pasting your code here and formatting problem or your Python code is not properly formatted at all.

Comment: I added the python file at the bottom of the post if it helps any @thesonyman101@ryugie @errata

Comment: @PhillipWard FYI, mentioning multiple users with "@" will trigger the message only for the first mentioned user, not the others ;)

Comment: Oh yikes! sorry yall!

Answer (score 0):

Your testing code is a mess, you don't need multiple turtles, just one, something along the lines:

```
def main():

    listofcolors = ("blue", "red", "yellow", "orange", "pink", "green")
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    mr = myRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, "blue")
    phil = turtle.Turtle()

    for _ in range(6):
        x = random.randint(-200, 200)
        print(x)
        y = random.randint(-200, 200)
        print(y)
        w = random.randint(1, 150)
        print(w)
        h = random.randint(1, 150)
        print(h)
        c = random.choice(listofcolors)
        print(c)

        mr.setX(x)
        mr.setY(y)
        mr.setWidth(w)
        mr.setHeight(h)
        mr.setColor(c)

        mr.draw(phil)

    wn.mainloop()

main()
```

This should bring you to step 7 in your instructions.

I don't know what your `__var__()` function is supposed to do, it seems like a lengthy no-op.  Your `draw()` function slightly tweaked:

```
    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(self.getX(), self.getY())
        turtle.setheading(0)
        turtle.color(self.getColor())  # set both pen & fill color
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(self.__width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(self.__height)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(self.__width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(self.__height)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the code you pasted in the post is not the same as in the file you list.  In the file you have an error on line 92 where you don't supply any args to setColor:

```
for i in [phil, macie, sashi, roxie, darla, sammy]:
    mr.setColor()
    mr.setX(xy)
    mr.setY(xy)
    mr.setWidth(wh)
    mr.setHeight(wh)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I think the indentation was just a formatting error, but I posted the download link for the file at the bottom of the post if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: the code you pasted above isn't the same as the code in the file

Comment: in the file your first call has no args:
    for i in [phil, macie, sashi, roxie, darla, sammy]:
        mr.setColor()
        mr.setX(xy)

Comment: I changed it to "mr.setColor(c)". I need to call the "draw" function from line 53ish under the for loop. However I get this error:  mr.draw(self,turtle)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined